# how to write a language for context-free grammar generates the empty string?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, context-free

How would you write a language for a context-free grammar that generates an empty string. Is it something like E = { (G) | G is a CFG and L(G) = Ø}?

Comment: If $L(G) = \emptyset$ then $G$ doesn't generate the empty string, since it doesn't generate *any* strings.

Comment: Does it generate only the empty string or the empty string with perhaps some others? From your second sentence, it appears the former.